# How to detect element click efficiently in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my link function for my directive

```
    function linkFunc(scope, element, attr){

        // Detect Element Click Logic
        scope.myCtrl.clickedElsewhere = {value: true};

        $document.on('click', function(){
            scope.myCtrl.clickedElsewhere.value = true;
            scope.$apply();
        });

        element.on('click', function(){
            event.stopPropagation();
            scope.myCtrl.clickedElsewhere.value = false;
            scope.$apply();
        });
        // End Detect Element Click Logic

    }
```

As we can see, we used `$document.on()` and `scope.apply` , this means that for every click on anywhere in the document we will trigger a digest cycle. If we have alot of `$watch` triggers this might cause the web page to slow down. Although this implementation is not every efficient, I can't think of other ways to detect on element click and off element click for expanding and contracting my element.

Can someone provide some insight?

Thanks

Comment: @Casey Hmm, but how would I detect off element click for contraction? I need to expand my list when clicked, but contract my list when user click on some other element. ng-click seems to only detect on element click.

Comment: Why do you need to run `$scope.apply()` on each document click?

Comment: Wouldn't you use `ng-blur` then?

Comment: @charlietfl If I don't use `$scope.apply` the variables only updates once, I am not exactly sure why that happens, however if I put console in the console get called multiple times

Comment: @MatthewGreen If we look at the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngEventDirs.js#L3]) of `ng-blur` it runs `$scope.apply` too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it would be a lot more efficient to check `scope.myCtrl.clickedElsewhere.value` before calling `$apply()` in the document click handler:

```
$document.on('click', function(){
   if(!scope.myCtrl.clickedElsewhere.value){
       scope.myCtrl.clickedElsewhere.value = true;
       scope.$apply();
   }
});
```

This will prevent needless digests when there is no change in it's status.

---

You could also remove this click listener and reapply it when you click on element:

```
function docHandler() {
  if (!scope.myCtrl.clickedElsewhere.value) {
    scope.myCtrl.clickedElsewhere.value = true;
    scope.$apply();
    $document.off('click');//remove event listener completely
  }
}

element.on('click', function() {
  event.stopPropagation();
  scope.myCtrl.clickedElsewhere.value = false;
  scope.$apply();
  $document.on('click', docHandler);// add document listener
});
```

Comment: Quick question, does `.off` potentially effect other directives that registered `click` listeners for `document`?

Comment: Yes...but since it seems you are using jQuery you can namespace event listeners also  like `$document.on('click.someClickName'...` and `$document.off('click.someClickName')` then other ones aren't affected

Answer (score 2):

You could just create an click off directive

```
myApp.directive('clickOff', function($parse, $document) {
  var dir = {
    compile: function($element, attr) {
      // Parse the expression to be executed
      // whenever someone clicks _off_ this element.
      var fn = $parse(attr["clickOff"]);
      return function(scope, element, attr) {
        // add a click handler to the element that
        // stops the event propagation.
        element.bind("click", function(event) {
          event.stopPropagation();
        });
        angular.element($document[0].body).bind("click",function(event) {
            scope.$apply(function() {
                fn(scope, {$event:event});
            });
        });
      };
    }
  };
  return dir;
});
```

Usage:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <button ng-click="show=true;" click-off="show=false;">
      Click Me
  </button>
  <div class="message" ng-show="show" ng-init="show = false">
    You clicked on the button. Now click anywhere else...
  </div>
</div>
```

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/oytdwyxj/

Comment: This feels a lot more angular to me.

Answer (score 0):

You could create two directives, with a parent/child relationship between them.

Take a look at the accordion directive that I created, which I believe that is what you need to in order to figure out your situation.

Directives:

```
app.directive("accordion", function () {
    return {
        template: "<div ng-transclude></div>",
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            closeall: "@"
        },
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            var itensScope = [];

            var addItemScope = function (scope) {
                itensScope.push(scope);
            };

            var closeItens = function () {
                if ($scope.closeall == "false") return;
                angular.forEach(itensScope, function (scope) {
                    scope.showItem = false;
                });
            }
            return {
                addItemScope: addItemScope,
                closeItens: closeItens
            };
        }
    };
});
app.directive("accordionItem", function () {
    return {
        template: "<div><div class='item' ng-class='{itemClose: !showItem}'>{{title}}</div><div class='itemInformation' ng-show='showItem' ng-transclude></div></div>",
        restrict: "E",
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            title: "@"
        },
        require: "^accordion",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transcludeFn) {
            ctrl.addItemScope(scope);
            element.bind("click", function () {
                ctrl.closeItens();
                scope.$apply(function () { 
                    scope.showItem = !scope.showItem; 
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Usage:

```
<accordion closeall="true">
        <accordion-item title="A">
            <p>
                A
            </p>
        </accordion-item>
        <accordion-item title="B">
            <p>
                B
            </p>
        </accordion-item>
</accordion>
```

I created this example a while ago and it is available in my GitHub: https://github.com/rodrigobranas/branas-angular-ui